# Unzip gradle dependencies using artifact name

Tags: gradle, dependencies, unzip

I'm looking for a way to extract a project's dependencies for a certain configuration into a workspace folder. As there might be more than one dependency I want to extract each artifact into a folder with the artifact's name. I'm trying to solve this in the context of python but this question is not really python related...

Currently my gradle file looks like this:

```
configurations { python }

dependencies {
  python group: 'github.dpeger', name: 'py-utils', version: '1.6', ext: 'zip'
  python group: 'github.dpeger', name: 'py-test', version: '1.6', ext: 'zip'
}

task cleanPythonDependencies(type: Delete) { delete 'lib/python' }
tasks.clean.dependsOn cleanPythonDependencies

task importPythonDependencies(type: Copy) {
  dependsOn cleanPythonDependencies
  from {
    configurations.python.collect { zipTree(it) }
  }
  into 'lib/python'
}
```

This however extracts all dependencies in the `python` configuration into the folder `lib\pyhton` without using the artifacts' names.

What I want is that `py-utils` gets extracted to `lib\pyhton\py-utils` and `py-test` to `lib\pyhton\py-test`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want py-utils extracted to lib\pyhton\py-utils and py-test to lib\pyhton\**py-test**, this should do the job:

```
task importPythonDependencies() {
  dependsOn cleanPythonDependencies

  String collectDir = 'lib/python'
  outputs.dir collectDir

  doLast {
    configurations.python.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
      copy {
        from zipTree( artifact.getFile() )
        into collectDir + '/' + artifact.name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. However I modified your answer a little bit (see edit of the question) as - with your task - the artifacts would have been copied to the lib-folder during the configuration phase of gradle. This would very likely cause problems with the cleanup, as the dependent task `cleanPythonDependencies` will be executed after the configuration phase and thus delete all extracted artifacts again...

Comment: Glad it helped. I have modified the answer to reflect your comments. I did not consider the cleanup when I tried. Nonetheless, it should not be part of the configuration phase as you pointed out.